# How to keep inline add if error is returned on pressing save action button in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

jgGrid contains inline add button in toolbar and save action button in action column.
Remote json data is used.
If save action button is pressed to terminate inline add and server returns error,
added row is removed from grid and entered row data is lost.
I added restoreAfterError:false to formatoptions 
and to inline add button as shown in code below but those settings are ignored if save action button is pressed.

How to keep row in inline add mode so that edit can continue after error if save action button is pressed?

```
colModel: [ {
  name:"_actions",
  formatter:"actions",
  formatoptions:{
    editbutton:true,
    keys:true,
    // this is ignored if action column save button is pressed:
    restoreAfterError:false,
    delbutton:true
    }
} , ...
], 
editurl: '/Grid/Edit',
datatype: "json",
```

inline add button is added using:

```
$grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#grid_toppager', {
    addParams: {
        position: "beforeSelected", 
        rowID: '_empty',
        useDefValues: true,
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true,
            // this is ignored if action column save button is pressed:
            restoreAfterError: false,
        }
    },

    editParams: {
            keys: true,
            // this is ignored if action column save button is pressed:
            restoreAfterError: false,
    },

   add: true,
   edit: false,
   save: true,
   cancel: true
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the settings `restoreAfterError: false` inside of `addParams.addRowParams` or `editParams` and it works good. In case of error the editing (or new added row) stay in the editing mode after the error message are displayed by my custom `errorfunc`. I suppose you had problems only in case of usage of `formatter: 'actions'`.

If you use the `formatter: 'actions'` you have no way to define `restoreAfterError` directly (at least in the current jqGrid version 3.4.1). So I recommend you to change the default value of `restoreAfterError` to `false`:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, {
    restoreAfterError: false
});
```

Additionally I recommend you remove trailing comma (like here `restoreAfterError: false,}`) from the `addRowParams` or `editParams`. Trailing commas are ignored by many (but not all) of web browsers, but there are still an error.

Comment: thank you. setting restoreAfterError using code in answer does not resolve the issue. I changed restoreAfterError in 2 places in jqGrid source code and this solves the issue. How to make `$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, { 
    restoreAfterError: false 
}); 
` to work or find the reason of the issue? I'm using code patched from git for inlineEdit

Comment: @Andrus: I tested my suggestion on [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridExportToExcel_editerror.zip) which used **original jqGrid 4.3.1**. jqGrid 4.3.1 have some known bugs, but the described features work correctly. I just commented in the demo the main code of `ModifyGridData` so editing returns always an error. If I use `restoreAfterError: false` in `addParams.addRowParams` and `editParams` part of `inlineNav` properties or if I use `$.extend($.jgrid.inlineEdit, {restoreAfterError: false});` (see commented part in Index.aspx) - both works.

Comment: @Andrus: So you should have some problem in *your modified code* of jqGrid.

Comment: I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2010. Got error `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Runtime` trying to run this solution. I searched whole solution but havent found any reference to this assembly. No idea why it requires this and how to remove this reference

Comment: @Andrus: The problem is the Visual Studio 2012 beta which I installed recently. I will fix the problem in the Project on another computer and will post you the updated demo later.

Comment: @Andrus: I updated [the demo project](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridExportToExcel_editerror.zip).